# Как задать параметр sortbyTVType в строке get-параметров запроса для сортировки вывода getResources?

Tags: modx

Привет всем.

Просветите по поводу сортировки в getResources.

Вот так выглядит строка с параметрами сортировки по TV **area**:

```
http://site.ru/catalog?sortby=area&sortdir=desc
```

А как сюда добавить тип сортировки sortbyTVType?
Пробовал так:

```
http://site.ru/catalog?sortby=area&sortdir=desc&sortbytype=integer
```

и так:

```
http://site.ru/catalog?sortby=area&sortdir=desc&sortbytvtype=integer
```

и так:

```
http://site.ru/catalog?sortby=area&sortdir=desc&sortby_type=integer
```

Answer (score 1):

Для сортировки по TV скорее нужно юзать

```
sortbyTV - переменная шаблона
sortdirTV - DESC или ASC
sortbyTVType - string, integer, decimal, datetime
```

Comment: Это понятно. Это в месте вызова сниппета. Мне нужно было знать, есть ли у параметра sortbyTVType эквивалентный параметр $_GET. Оказалось - нет.